# What does 「うめる」means in this sentence?

Tags: words

I've tried looking up this word in dictionaries + translate tools, it all say the word 「うめる」means is "to bury". 
So what does it mean in this sentence?

```
わかるところからうめるようにしましょう。
```

I read it on the start section of a textbook, so I guess it means something like "this book will explain everything a little by little", but I'm not sure is it true or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[埋]{う}める can also mean "to fill in (a form, blank)".

eg

> [空欄]{くうらん}を[埋]{う}めましょう。
>   Fill in the blanks.

---

To break your sentence into smaller chunks...

> わかる -- understand, know the answer to
>   ところ -- the part
>   から -- from, starting from
>   うめる -- fill in, fill up, fill out
>   ようにしましょう -- let's try, please try